# Writing a C++ program to print the letters of a string in a chaotic order

Tags: c++, string, random

What I'm trying to do is this:

- User enters a string (For example: "Hello")
- The program returns the same string, but in a random order(It can be "elHlo" or any other order possible)

So far I've written this code, but the problem is that sometimes the randomly generated numbers are the same, so it might print the same indexes(letters) twice or more times:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    cout << "Say something: ";
    string text;
    getline(cin, text);
    
    cout << "\nChaotic text: ";
    
    srand(time(0));
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<text.length(); j++){
        int randomLetter = rand()%text.length(); 
        
        cout << text.at(randomLetter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) (since C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    cout << "Say something: ";
    string text;
    getline(cin, text);
    
    cout << "\nChaotic text: ";

    std::mt19937 g(time(0));
 
    std::shuffle(text.begin(), text.end(), g);
    cout << text;

    return 0;
}
```

Or `std::random_shuffle` (if you are using old specification):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    cout << "Say something: ";
    string text;
    getline(cin, text);
    
    cout << "\nChaotic text: ";

    srand(time(0));
 
    std::random_shuffle(text.begin(), text.end());
    cout << text;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `rand()` one time, which can generate an index you have called before, you can keep generating a new index while keeping tracking of all generated indices in a hashtable.

```
std::unordered_map<int, bool> done;
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++) {
    int randomLetter = rand() % text.length();

    while (done[randomLetter] == true) // while it's been marked as finished, generate a new index.
        randomLetter = rand() % text.length();

    cout << text.at(randomLetter);
    done[randomLetter] = true; // mark it as finished.
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::random_shuffle` instead, which should save you the hassle.

```
std::random_shuffle (text.begin(), text.end());
std::cout << text << '\n';
```